# Text to HTML converter for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, converters, text-to-html

I need a script that converts plain text into HTML (eg like the one in reddit comments system). There are plenty of those out there, yeah, but I need one that could work with Google App Engine (and Python).

It could be great if the script could work both ways: for encoding the text and decoding it back from HTML (for editing saved texts).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple 'humane' markup languages, and no particular reason for any of them to not work in App Engine. My blog engine, bloggart, for example, supports [several](http://github.com/Arachnid/bloggart/tree/master/lib/) via their standard Python libraries.

Instead of attempting to convert HTML back to markup, you should be storing the original, un-mangled markup the user input, and allowing them to edit that, instead.